# Custom easing equation for counting big numbers

Tags: javascript, easing

I want to render the counting from 0 to some very big number, lets say 1,000,000 in 3 seconds, which is somewhat a short time to count to a million.

### [live playground](http://goo.gl/PUKVjV)

The problem is, it needs a very specific easing so the counting effect will be at its "best", and that would be starting slow, counting the first 10% (of the ***duration***) slow, then speed up till ~60% of the duration, and then finish up slowing down gradually the rest of the time 40%.

Input is **always** between `0` and `1`.
How to approach creating such an easing formula?

---

Should be in this manner, where given `t` is between `0` to `1` (basic example):

```
function(t){ return t*t; }
```

I bacially have a function which runs a code on each "frame" of the animation proccess, and it goes through a frame rate throttler, and the `t` value is the current progress on a given time duration.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=easing+function+generator

Comment: @Bergi - I wouldn't have posted if I haven't done my research and found nothing

Comment: So what did you find? How was it not helpful?

Comment: @Bergi - well, those aren't mathematical easing functions, but independent functions which do a lot more than easing, since they require many arguments which are irrelevant to me, since I want the easing to be done mathematically like the easing functions I already use in my example, this is how everything is configured.

Comment: Maybe use the fibonacci sequence as a basic speed measurement for the delay of the function?

Comment: @vsync: they are normal easing function that do require "configuration parameters", which you do want to find so that your points (150/1000000 at 0.1, and 990000/1000000 at 0.6) are interpolated, and that `t` (time) argument. Just play around with different curve forms and configs so that they best match your expected effect.

Comment: @Bergi - I'm sorry but I do not want those things at all, I explicitly want a mathematical equation, as the example above. it must be in that format, this is how the program is designed, with **complete** seperation between logic and math. I dislike the idea that some easing function will handle code for me. I do that elsewhere, things will not work otherwise.

Comment: @vsync: Easing functions are mathematical equations! Not sure what your problem is with that. Just pick any you like, like [cubic-bezier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) or whatever, then play around with it until you get the expected shape like http://cubic-bezier.com/#.55,0,.15,1, then you've got your equation.

Comment: @Bergi - but I need it to work with 1 value, why are you insulting me like that. you don't have to call it `easing`, it's only terminology. single variable equation. just like [these](https://github.com/overjase/snap-easing/blob/master/snap.svg.easing.js), and [these](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294), and [this](https://github.com/CharlotteGore/functional-easing). **very** common simple easing functions. Now you understand better?

Comment: @vsync: Yes, cubic bezier functions (for example) do take exactly one value, `t`, see the explicit form of the curve formula in the Wikipedia article I linked (`P_0 = (0, 0), P_3 = (1, 1000000)` for your case). You just have to find the points 1 and 2 so that the curve goes through the values you like. Just like that [`easingFunction.withParameters( ... )`](https://github.com/CharlotteGore/functional-easing#easingfunctionwithparameters--) you linked - very common indeed.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Gompertz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function)?

e.g. something like (constants from some algebra to estimate + some cheating experimentation, so the numbers aren't exactly what you specified):

```
function ease_gompertz(t) {
    return 1000000 * Math.exp(-30 * Math.exp(-13 * t));
}
```

For that I assumed t goes from 0 to 1.  Take a look at the wikipedia page to understand the meaning of the constants.

Here are some sample values from that function (the stars pick out the values you specifed):

```
0.0 0 *
0.1 281 *
0.2 107721
0.3 544843
0.4 847472
0.5 955899
0.6 987783 *
0.7 996656
0.8 999087
0.9 999751
1.0 999932 *
```

or, divided by 1E6:

```
0.0 0.00000 *
0.1 0.00028 *
0.2 0.10772
0.3 0.54484
0.4 0.84747
0.5 0.95590
0.6 0.98778 *
0.7 0.99666
0.8 0.99909
0.9 0.99975
1.0 0.99993 *
```

P.S. In case of confusion if I messed up the JS: I confess I tested this at a Python prompt, not JS.

Comment: Unlike a normal easing function, the gompertz function does never reach the value `1` - it's only asymptotic.

Comment: As the input is between 0-1 the output too should be between 0-1, only modified. even without the `1000000 *` it still doesn't ease-out. some examples for input/output: `0.1/0.11` `0.2/0.5` `0.5/0.9` `0.8/0.98` .. start slow, go fast, and end slowly

Comment: @vsync: I can't tell whether you're saying those values are what you get out of my Gompertz function or that those values are what you want?  If the former: I don't think that's correct.  If the latter: that seems to contradict what you wrote in your question, which was that 0 should map to 0, 0.1 should map to about 200, 0.6 should map to about 9.9E5, and 1 should map to 1E6 (or all those divided by 1E6, if you prefer).

Comment: @Bergi: For the application (which involves integers), I think if you choose appropriate constants that shouldn't matter, because you can make it reach whatever integer you like.

Comment: @vsync: the Gompertz function does indeed "start slow, go fast, and end slowly"

Comment: @CroadLangshan - I see...I will edit my question, there's a big misunderstand I think. Lets assume the input can only be between 0 and 1, and what I commented was the latter

Comment: Thanks! it works pretty nice. check out the [million example](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/deoxg?editors=101). how can I slow it a bit more at the end?

Comment: Seems you just removed the example values from the question?  I'm none the wiser, sorry :-)  Can you just explicitly tabulate some wanted example values, as I have in my answer?